# Xampp: Php_redis.dll could not be loaded

Tags: php, redis, xampp

I use `XAMPP 1.8.3`, `PHP 5.5.9`, `TS`, `VC11`. My OS is `Windows 7 Ultimate x86`, up-to-date.

Recently I wanted to add `php_redis.dll` extension. I downloaded `php_redis-2.2.4-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip` from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/redis/2.2.4/), as well as the `php_igbinary.dll`. Both files are in the php/ext folder.

The php.ini is correct. The extensions are not commented out, the path is OK, the IG-Binary.dll is visible in phpinfo()-output. My PATH contains a path to the extensions folder.

Only Redis makes problems. Each time when starting Apache it says:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp183\php\ext\php_redis.dll' - The specified module has not been found.

I am desperated, because I have tried everything with no result. Please help!

Comment: Same issue here, cannot get any working drivers on windows 7, 64 bit.  IIS in my case.

Comment: Here I found WORKING libs.
http://char101.github.io/phpredis/

But d'oh, no PHP 5.5 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download windows extension DLLs here.

https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/2.2.7/windows

http://www.9lessons.info/2014/01/getting-started-with-redis-chatting.html